# Passing structure to function gives wierd errors in c

Tags: c, struct

I have this very simple structure:

```
typedef struct contact{
    char name[80];
    char surname[80];
    char cellnumber[20];
    float hight;
}contact;
```

and i want to try to pass it to the function to insert a contact:

```
void insertcontact(contact){
    printf("Insert name of contact: ");
    fgets(contact.name,80,stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Insert surname of contact: ");
    fgets(contact.surname,80,stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Insert celphone number of contact: ");
    fgets(contact.cellnumber,20,stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Insert length of contact: ");
    scanf("%f",&contact.hight);
    getchar();
}
```

but I get some errors when I do:

`error: parameter name omitted` , `error: expected expression before ‘contact’`and `error: too few arguments to function ‘fgets’`

these last two errors occure for every fgets function i have and i think it has to do with the structure as well. does anybody know what this means?

Answer (score 4):

Give your parameter a name:

```
void insertcontact(contact _contact){
    printf("Insert name of contact: ");
    fgets(_contact.name,80,stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Insert surname of contact: ");
    fgets(_contact.surname,80,stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Insert celphone number of contact: ");
    fgets(_contact.cellnumber,20,stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Insert length of contact: ");
    scanf("%f",&_contact.hight);
    getchar();
}
```

When you do this:

```
typedef struct contact
{
...
}contact;
```

You have just given your struct a new type-name (*synonyms* for types), hence you need to pass a name of the parameter with its type in the method.

Comment: @CoderGuy , Also, I don't think you need those `getchar()`s as `fgets()` comsumes the `\n` character